# Vue doesn't update when computed data change

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuejs2

Context: I have a list of posts with tags, categories from wordpress api. I display these posts with `Vue` and using `computed` with a search box to filter the result based on titre, description, tags, and categories

Problem: I am trying to update a `computed` list when user click on a list of tag available. I add the `get` and `set` for `computed` data like this:

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#blogs',       
    data: {
        search: '',
        posts: [],
        filterPosts: []
    },
    beforeMount: function() {
        // It should call the data and update
        callData();
    },
    computed: {
        filterPosts: {
            get: function() {
                var self = this;
                return self.posts.filter(function(post){
                    var query = self.search.toLowerCase();
                    var title = post.title.toLowerCase();
                    var content = post.content.toLowerCase();
                    var date = post.date.toLowerCase();
                    var categories = '';
                    post.categories.forEach(function(category) {
                       categories += category.name.toLowerCase(); 
                    });
                    var tags = '';
                    post.tags.forEach(function(tag){
                        tags += tag.name.toLowerCase();
                    });
                    return title.indexOf(query) !== -1 ||content.indexOf(query) !== -1 || date.indexOf(query) !== -1 || categories.indexOf(query) !== -1 || tags.indexOf(query) !== -1;
                });
            },
            set: function (newValue) {
                console.log(newValue);
                this.filterPosts = Object.assign({}, newValue);
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        filterByTag: function(tag, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var self = this;
            self.filterPosts = self.posts.filter(function(post){
                var tags = '';
                post.tags.forEach(function(tag){
                    tags += tag.name.toLowerCase();
                });
                return tags.indexOf(tag.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            });
        }
    }
}); // Vue instance
```

The `console.log` always output new data based on the function I wrote on `methods` but `Vue` didn't re-render the view. I think I didn't do the right way or thought like `Vue`. Could you please give some insight?

**Edit 1**
Add full code.

I tried to add `filterPosts` in `data` but I received this error from Vue: `The computed property "filterPosts" is already defined in data.`

Comment: not clear at all... share more code

Comment: I will add now some new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going around and around, I found a solution, I think it may be the right way with Vue now: Update the computed data through its dependencies properties or data.

The `set` method didn't work for this case so I add an `activeTag` in `data`, when I click on a tag, it will change the `activeTag` and notify the computed `filterPost` recheck and re-render. Please tell me if we have another way to update the `computed` data.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#blogs',       
    data: {
        search: '',
        posts: [],
        tags: [],
        activeTag: ''
    },
    beforeMount: function() {
        // It should call the data and update
        callData();
    },
    computed: {
        filterPosts: {
            get: function() {
                var self = this;
                return self.posts.filter(function(post){
                    var query = self.search.toLowerCase();
                    var title = post.title.toLowerCase();
                    var content = post.content.toLowerCase();
                    var date = post.date.toLowerCase();
                    var categories = '';
                    post.categories.forEach(function(category) {
                       categories += category.name.toLowerCase(); 
                    });
                    var tags = '';
                    post.tags.forEach(function(tag){
                        tags += tag.name.toLowerCase();
                    });
                    var activeTag = self.activeTag;
                    if (activeTag !== '') {
                        return tags.indexOf(activeTag.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
                    }else{
                        return title.indexOf(query) !== -1 ||content.indexOf(query) !== -1 || date.indexOf(query) !== -1 || categories.indexOf(query) !== -1 || tags.indexOf(query) !== -1;
                    }                       
                });
            },
            set: function (newValue) {
                console.log(newValue);
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        filterByTag: function(tag, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var self = this;
            self.activeTag = tag;
        }
    }
}); // Vue instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setter is actually not setting anything, it only logs the new value. You need to store it somewhere.

For example you can store it in the component's data:

```
data: {
  value: 'foo',
},
computed: {
  otherValue: {
    get() { /*...*/ },
    set(newVal) { this.value = newVal },
  },
},
```

But this is definitely not the only possibility, if you use Vuex, the setter can dispatch an action that will then make the computed value get updated. The component will eventually catch the update and show the new value.

```
computed: {
  value: {
    get() {
      return this.$store.getters.externalData;
    },
    set(newVal) {
      return this.$store.dispatch('modifyingAction', newVal);
    },
  },
},
```

The bottomline is you have to trigger a data change in the setter, otherwise your component will not be updated nor will it trigger any rerender.

---

EDIT (The original answer was updated with full code):

The answer is that unless you want to manually change the list `filteredPosts` without altering `posts`, you don't need a `get` and `set` function for your computed variable. The behaviour you want can be acheived with this:

```
const vm = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      posts: [], 
      // these should probably be props, or you won't be able to edit the list easily. The result is the same anyway.
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      return this.posts.filter(function(post) {
        ... // do the filtering
      });
    },
  },
  template: "<ul><li v-for='post in filteredPosts'>{{ post.content }}</li></ul>",
});
```

This way, if you change the `posts` or the `search` variable in `data`, `filteredPosts` will get recomputed, and a re-render will be triggered.

Comment: I set the value in the `methods` function, in the `newValue`, it is already showed, for the data part, I didn't put `filterPosts` but only `posts`, should I add an empty `filterPosts` in data first?

Comment: I just added the full code, I may try vuex next time but now I just want to know how make it work

Comment: You don't need a `filterPost` in `data`. What you want is to add the new post in the `posts` variable. `filterPosts` will get recomputed and your new item should then show up. 
Basically, vue tracks the vars in `data`, `props` (etc...) used to evaluate the `calculated` ones, and triggers a recalculation when they are changed.

Comment: yeah, so I add `activeTag` into `filterPosts` and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
  data: {
    myValue: 'OK'
  },
  computed: {
    filterPosts: {
      get: function () {
        return this.myValue + ' is OK'
      }
      set: function (newValue) {
        this.myValue = newValue
      }
    }
  }
```

More:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter